# populating prefixed fields - bug or feature?

Tags: django, django-forms

Having the following models:

```
#models.py
Column(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

Input(models.Model):
    column = ForeignKey(Column)
    text = models.CharField()
```

And the following form:

```
class InputForm(Modelform):

    class Meta():
        model=Input
```

The following works:
    c = Column.objects.get(...)
    i=InputForm({'column':c.id})

```
i.is_valid() #true
```

In my application I am generating many forms, to avoid clashes I prefix it:

```
i=InputForm({'column':c.id}, prefix=prfx()) #prfx() is dynamically generated
i.errors # ({'column':['This field is required']})
```

`i.data['column']` is still the right value

I also tried:

```
i.column = c
i.errors # ({'column':['This field is required']})
```

How do I populate the `column` field?
I cannot save the form as long as it does not validate

**EDIT** What I am trying to achieve:

I am building dynamic forms:

```
form_list = [InputForm(column, prefix=column.id) for column in col_list]
```

In the template I iterate over this form list (and I want to set the `column` field to be invisible.

```
{% for form in form_list %}
   {{form.as_ul}}
{%endfor%}
```

This form then shall be processed by an AjaxView. The relation between `text` and `column` is achieved by the invisible field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter to the form is the input data, which is usually `request.POST`. If you render a `Form` with a prefix, you will see that all form html elements will have a prefixed name, for example `<input name='yourprefix_text' />` etc. If you POST such a form to your Django app, the POSTed data will have the prefix, too.

So, if you are using a prefix, the input data needs to be prefixed, too:

```
f = InputForm({'yourprefix_column': c.id}, prefix='yourprefix')
```

Usually, it is a better idea to [use the `initial` parameter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values) to the form for default values, because otherwise the form is always bound, and this has some consequences, for example default/initial values for other fields are will not work.

```
f = InputForm(prefix='yourprefix', initial={'column': c})
# or ...
form_list = [InputForm(prefix=column.id, initial={'column': column})
             for column in col_list]
```

If you want to *always* set the column to a programatically determined value, and not allow the user to change it, it is better to not include the field in your form, and set the field manually after saving the object:

```
f = InputForm(request.POST)
if f.is_valid():
    instance = f.save(commit=False)
    instance.column = c
    instance.save()
```

To make your field hidden, you can change the widget, [as described in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields):

```
class InputForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'column': forms.HiddenInput,
        }
        # ...
```

Comment: Thanks so far, in the Edit, I tried to describe, what I wanted to achieve: I need to set `column` when creating the form to be able to establish the relationship between `column` and `text`

Comment: You should be able to do so with the `initial` parameter. Be aware, though, that the user can change these hidden fields at will, so you might need additional validation, depending on your application